# Compile vNode inside a function and have it appended to regular dom with vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

This example is importing vue via a cdn link in a shopify site. The typical way of using vue like this is to create a vue app for a certain part of the page, so the below example assumes we are on a product page. What I am struggling with is that inside a certain function, for example `openModal`, we might want some vue code inside the function but this code will not be compiled.

For example:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"></div>

  <!-- Mount the vue app here -->
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <button @click="openModal">open modal</button>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<script type="module">
const { createApp } = Vue

const product_app = Vue.createApp({
  compilerOptions: {
    delimiters: ['{', '}']
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sizeOptions: ['xs', 's', 'm']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      // append modal to the DOM
      // ...

      const modal_inner = document.querySelector('.modal-inner')

      // vue template code
      // this of course will not be compiled by vue
      const modal_content = `
        <div v-for="size in sizeOptions"
          class="sizeSwatch"
        >{ sizeOption }</div>
      `;

      modal_inner.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', modal_content)
    }
  }
})

product_app.mount(document.querySelector('.product-wrapper'))
</script>
```

Since this is not in a vue app, and there is no build step, the above example is usually solved like this - wherein the vue template code we need for later is rendered in the app in a wrapper div with the display set to none, later we just clone it.

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"></div>

  <!-- Mount the vue app here -->
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <button @click="openModal">open modal</button>

    <div class="hidden">
      <div v-for="size in sizeOptions" 
        class="sizeSwatch"
      >{ sizeOption }</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

My idea was to do something like this but I don't know how to do this and that is what this question is about, if the below example can be made to work.

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"></div>

  <!-- Mount the vue app here -->
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <button @click="openModal">open modal</button>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<script type="module">
const { createApp } = Vue

const product_app = Vue.createApp({
  compilerOptions: {
    delimiters: ['{', '}']
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sizeOptions: ['xs', 's', 'm']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      // append modal to the DOM
      // ...

      const modal_inner = document.querySelector('.modal-inner')

      const modal_content = h(
        'div',
        this.sizeOptions.map(sizeOption) => {
          return h('div', sizeOption)
        })
      )

      // somehow append the vnode to the modal
    }
  }
})

product_app.mount(document.querySelector('.product-wrapper'))
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

This does work and the vnode will be appended to the end of the selector. If anyone knows a better way please post a solution, I am not sure yet if there are any caveats to doing this regarding reactivity but in my use case it seems to be working just fine.

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"></div>

  <!-- Mount the vue app here -->
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <button @click="openModal">open modal</button>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<script type="module">
const { createApp } = Vue

const product_app = Vue.createApp({
  compilerOptions: {
    delimiters: ['{', '}']
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sizeOptions: ['xs', 's', 'm']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      // append modal to the DOM
      // ...

      const modal_inner = document.querySelector('.modal-inner')

      const vnode = Vue.h(
        'div',
        this.sizeOptions.map(sizeOption) => {
          return Vue.h('div', sizeOption)
        })
      )

      Vue.render(vnode, document.querySelector('.modal-inner'))
    }
  }
})

product_app.mount(document.querySelector('.product-wrapper'))
</script>
```

Comment: It's not done this way. You either render it in existing app and its template, or create a new app with different root. Since the template is likely the content of .product-wrapper, means that you need to add the things you need to it prior to mounting

Comment: The way I was doing it was I had to mount an app in the`openModal` function but it annoyed me I had to keep doing this and thought maybe I could just get vue to render out the html based on the surrounding app

Comment: @EstusFlask there is a way to do this apparently, I found it on chat gpt and had to play around with it a lot and I haven't been able to find it yet in the docs. See the updated answer.

Comment: `render` is internal, I'd advise against using a thing that works in uncertain way. I doubt that reactivity will correctly work this way. As mentioned above, proper options are to modify a template to render modal comp the same way you'd do with regular Vue app, or use another app instance for it and sync two apps together to make the reactivity work